# AngularJs deep linking to a specific ng-view

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, deep-linking

I followed a tutorial on angularJS with subviews using ng-views

I'm using html5Mode in my locationProvider and a nodejs backend

If I wanted to link to or hit refresh while on a specific ng-view, I could use a hashtag. So like, to explain: if my angular app lived on localhost:3000/app and I had a view at localhost:3000/app/subview, if I hit refresh my node server didn't know how to go to a specific view on the front end.

But if, on the server side, a request came through for /app/subview and I redirected to or rendered /app#/subview (with the hashtag in there), then I went to the correct ng-view on the front end. That's what I wanted. Of course, there's more than one way to skin a cat I guess, but it was working.

Now, I'm trying to do that again. But this time it's not working.

If I try to go to localhost:3000/app#/subview via a link or refresh, instead of going to the ng-view that lives at /app/subview like it did before, it's going to /app#%2Fsubview instead. And I'm ..heh .. heh.. not sure what's different. I thought I was doing everything exactly the same.

Has anyone had this problem? Does anyone know what is happening?

Edit:
I think I kind of found a workaround. If I set base href = "/app" in the head of the html document, and then respond to a request to app/subview with a redirect to app#/subview, then I can serve up app with the correct subview (only the url goes to /subview). I think this might be acceptable for me even if it's not quite ideal but OH WELL

Comment: %2F is the url encode for '/'. Try to go to /app/#/subview

Comment: Going to /app/#/subview is still getting rewrriten as /app#%2Fsubview

Comment: It sounds like you have your html5 mode misconfigured (propably on the server).

Comment: Hmm. Thought for sure it was an angular thing.